# how to make a gap when code already sent a request

Tags: jquery

when my text autocomplete already send a request to server then i want to make a new gap when he goes to send a new request.

means when a request goes

then he not make a new request for some millisecond then it can be say that "how i can make gap between two request goes to sever"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you might want to try looking at this plugin.

[jQuery Block UI Demo page](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#demos)

> The jQuery BlockUI Plugin lets you
>   simulate synchronous behavior when
>   using AJAX, without locking the
>   browser. When activated, it will
>   prevent user activity with the page
>   (or part of the page) until it is
>   deactivated. BlockUI adds elements to
>   the DOM  to give it both the
>   appearance and behavior of blocking
>   user interaction.